# Android: After application update on Google Play, icon and app name are not updated

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that's already uploaded to Google play and opened for beta testing. I changed icon and title of app, signed and uploaded to Play.

After update I realized that Samsung galaxy S4 (KitKat) still keeps old icon and name. I have also Galaxy S5 and it's ok there.

Why icon and  name  didn't  updated?

Comment: are you able to download from playstore

Answer (score 1):

Google updates apk graphic when you upload it into console. 
You need to wait. I had the same issue, and the icon updates in 1-2h after i published build.